# Select first image of current div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image

I just posted a similar question regarding this to find out it wasn't exactly what I needed. My apologies.

This is the code I am working with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

  $('.upload_button').click(function() {

    targetfield = $(this).prev('.logo_url');
    tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');

    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
      imgurl = $('img',html).attr('src');
      jQuery(targetfield).val(imgurl);
      tb_remove();

      $('.upload_preview img').attr('src',imgurl); // THIS IS WHERE I'M HAVING PROBLEMS

      $('#submit_options_form').trigger('click');
    };

    return false;

  });
});
```

I am not the best with jQuery and am still new to some things. I need to populate the url of the img tag in the preview class, but only on the one that is getting the url. What I have now will populate every image tag that has that class. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I need it to populate it like the input field gets populated.

EDIT

Here is some example HTML. I am using multiples of these on a page.

```
<li class="slide">

            <input class="logo_url" name="theme_wptuts_options[logo]" value="src[]" />
                <input class="upload_button" type="button" class="button" value="<?php _e( 'Upload Logo' ); ?>" />

                <div class="upload_preview" style="min-height: 100px;">
                    <img style="max-width:100%;" src="src[]" />
                </div>

            <button class="remove_slide button-secondary">Remove This Slide</button>

</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error this is what I ended up with that works like I wanted. I appreciate everyone's help and answers.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
$('.upload_button').click(function() {
     targetfield = $(this).prev('.logo_url');
     imgpreview = $(this).parent().find('img');
     tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
     imgurl = $('img',html).attr('src');
     jQuery(targetfield).val(imgurl);
     tb_remove();
     $(imgpreview).attr('src', imgurl);
     $('#submit_options_form').trigger('click');
};
return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Such a simple solution...too bad finding it is rarely easy! Good work Man!

Answer (score 2):

use :eq(0), it will pick first element, imho the best way compared to .first() .last() etc :)

```
$('.upload_preview img:eq(0)').attr('src',imgurl);
```

Answer (score 1):

imgurl**EDITED 11/05/2012 9:47pm ET**

This might be it! I cant test in the fiddle because I cant perform the window.send function in the fiddle.

[Revised Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/SZF4Y/5/)

**JQuery**

```
var whichLi;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('.upload_button').click(function() {

       whichLi= $(this).parent('li');

       targetfield = $(this).prev('.logo_url');
        tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');

        window.send_to_editor = function(html) {


            imgurl = $('img', html).attr('src');
            jQuery(targetfield).val(imgurl);
            tb_remove();

            $(whichLi).find('img').attr('src', imgurl);
            $('#submit_options_form').trigger('click');
        };

        return false;

    });
});
```

Comment: I tried using "this" with no luck, I believe because it is within another function right? So I used '.upload_button' in place of 'this' but it fills in every img field not just one :(

Comment: why not pull the this line of code below the window.sendtoeditor function? yet keep it inside the $('.upload_button').click() function? I don't see any if statements so it should be good..

Comment: It needs to be within window.sender though because the variable imgurl is what populates the img field.

Comment: Ok, got it...decalre a global variable such as 'var whichLi;' as I did above...before the window.send set that variable, then call to it via the $(whichLi) handler.

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, I added the answer, I finally figured it out. I created a variable that took the parent of the class then found the img tag so then I could use both variables to achieve a preview image. Thanks again for trying to help I appreciate it.

Comment: Just saw your answer, somewhat similar to what I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

`:first` selector do the work:

```
$('.upload_preview:first img').attr('src', imgurl);
```

Comment: This doesn't work :( it populates the very first instance of an img tag no matter what.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what you want?